# log4net not working when running WPF application's executable

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, log4net, log4net-configuration

I'm using log4net in a WPF application. log4net works when running the application from Visual Studio, however, it's not working when we run the application via the executable from `bin`.

We're using a `log4net.config` file, here's what it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="C:/ProgramData/CompApps/Logs/AppName/log.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="25" />
      <maximumFileSize value="20MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%utcdate UTC %property{log4net:HostName} [%thread] %-5level %logger - %method() - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="Info" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

`log4net.config` properties

```
Build Action: Content
Copy to Output Directory: Copy always
```

`AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
// log4net config
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

And this is used in each class we want to use the logger:

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(App));
```

Comment: Does the **user** running the application have write rights to `C:/ProgramData/CompApps/Logs/AppName/`?

Comment: Yes, the user running the application has write rights to `C:/ProgramData/CompApps/Logs/AppName/`

Comment: Does `debug="true"` make any sense to not log when executing from .exe ?

Comment: I removed the `debug="true"` flag - same result.

Comment: If you run it right from the `bin` folder does the `log4net.config` file also reside there next to the `.exe`? How have you tested that the execution context for the `.exe` has access to the `logs` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach for configuration in code:

```
namespace Company.Product
{
    using System.Text;
    using log4net;
    using log4net.Appender;
    using log4net.Core;
    using log4net.Layout;
    using log4net.Repository.Hierarchy;

    public static class LogHelper
    {
        static LogHelper()
        {
            var hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
            hierarchy.Root.Level = Level.All;
            hierarchy.Configured = true;
        }

        public static ILog GetLoggerRollingFileAppender(string logName, string fileName)
        {
            var log = LogManager.Exists(logName);

            if (log != null) return log;

            var appenderName = $"{logName}Appender";
            log = LogManager.GetLogger(logName);
            ((Logger)log.Logger).AddAppender(GetRollingFileAppender(appenderName, fileName));

            return log;
        }

        public static RollingFileAppender GetRollingFileAppender(string appenderName, string fileName)
        {
            var layout = new PatternLayout { ConversionPattern = "%date{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff}  [%-5level]  %message%newline" };
            layout.ActivateOptions();

            var appender = new RollingFileAppender
            {
                Name = appenderName,
                File = fileName,
                AppendToFile = true,
                RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Size,
                MaxSizeRollBackups = 2,
                MaximumFileSize = "500KB",
                Layout = layout,
                ImmediateFlush = true,
                LockingModel = new FileAppender.MinimalLock(),
                Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            };

            appender.ActivateOptions();

            return appender;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage for your case:

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogHelper.GetLoggerRollingFileAppender(typeof(App), "C:/ProgramData/CompApps/Logs/AppName/log.txt");
```

Or reference log file full path from your application config file.

Comment: This worked! One less configuration file to worry about. Good stuff!

Comment: how would this configuration change if I was wanting to use https://github.com/cjbhaines/Log4Net.Async#forwarding-appenders?

Comment: Can't test it because l currently from mobile, but did you try it and get any error? You will probably need to create rolling file appender from this custom library in configuration rather then from legacy log4net library. I have never used this nuget package before, so you should better create new question if things will not work.

Comment: Got it. Thanks Sam!

Comment: This work for me for start up project only. But when I try to log from other project I am not getting any log. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Renascent I would suggest to debug `GetLoggerRollingFileAppender` method call from within this "other" project and see what happening there in runtime, what loggers was actually created. That said, I'm currently haven't used WPF for years, so can't check it out...

Comment: Thanks @Sam for responding. I will check that and see if that helps. It seems that issue is with configuration and "other" projects are not able to get it. I will provide update once I resolve this. Thanks a lot.